# How to find the exact contributor count of a GitHub repository using GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to count the total number of contributors of a GitHub repository using the GitHub API. But, I did not get the exact number of contributors shown in the repository. For example, in the [azure-sdk-for-go](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) repository, the total number of contributors are shows as **188**.

[image]

Now, if I run the below query, I get **157** as result.

```
def contributorCount(u, r):
    return re.search('\d+$', requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/contributors?per_page=1'.format(u, r)).links['last']['url']).group()

print(contributorCount("Azure", "azure-sdk-for-go"))
```

If I add the **anon=True** in the URL, then I got **169** contributors.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/contributors?per_page=1&anon=true
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [this discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24355#discussioncomment-3243899), it might not be trivial to find the *same* number:

> A user can be “anonymous” if there is no GitHub user associated with a given email address.
>
> And the reason that your number still may not match the one given by the UI is because the same GitHub user may have contributed using multiple email addresses. This is why I said above:
>
> > on larger repos, you may not be able to replicate the exact figure that we show on the website.
>
> The API simply doesn’t return the information you need in order to be able to replicate the number we show.